# Как использовать компонент для разных путей с загрузкой различных данных для этого компонента?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

У меня есть компонент.

```
<template>
      <HotTable :settings="hotSettings" ></HotTable>
</template>

<script>
import HotTable from "@handsontable/vue";
import Handsontable from "handsontable";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
        hotSettings: {
          data: 
          [
            ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
            ["2016", "10", 11, 12, 13],
            ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 13],
            ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
          ],
          rowHeaders: true,
          colHeaders: true
        }
    };
  },
  components: {
    HotTable
  }
};
</script>
```

Этот компонент отображается по трём разным путям: `/path/path1`, `/path/path2`, `/path/path3`.
Как можно сделать так, чтобы, переходя по этим путям, на каждой странице отображался этот компонент, но данные для него (поле `data`) были разными?

Недавно подсказали использовать `props` в маршрутах. Получилось следующее.

Компонент

```
<template>
  <HotTable :data="myData"></HotTable>
</template>

<script>
import HotTable from "@handsontable/vue";
import Handsontable from "handsontable";

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {}
    };
  },
  props: ["myData"],
  components: {
    HotTable
  }
};
</script>

<style src="handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css"></style>
<style>
#hot-preview {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Файл с маршрутами

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [{
      path: '/tables/groups',
      component: Table,
      props: {
        myData: [
          ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
          ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13],
          ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 14],
          ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 15]
        ]
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/tables/subjects',
      component: Table,
      props: {
        myData: [
          ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
          ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 15],
          ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 14],
          ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
        ]
      },
    },
  ],
})
```

Данное решение рабочее, но мне необходимо динамически получать данные для таблицы, поэтому я использую хранилище. Как можно связать хранилище с данной конструкцией?

Файл `store.js`

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    groupsTableData: [],
  },
  actions: {
    loadGroupsTableData({commit}) {
      axios
        .get("/api/tables/groups")
        .then((response) => {
          commit("SET_GROUPS_TABLE_DATA", response.data);
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_GROUPS_TABLE_DATA(state, data) {
      state.groupsTableData = data;
    },
  },
  getters: {
    groupsTableData: state => {
      return state.groupsTableData
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Вариант 1: [`$watch` на `$route`](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81n%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)

- Инициализируем `data` значением `null`
- Используем [`$watch`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#watch) чтобы следить за [`$route`](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/api/#%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-route)
- В обработчике изменения получаем нужные данные из `store` в зависимости от текущего пути
- Вероятно, самый простой вариант (без использования дополнительных библиотек)

```
const tables = {
  '/path/path1': store => store.state.table1,
  '/path/path2': store => store.state.table2,
}

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      const path = to.path;
      this.data = tables[path](this.$store);
    }
  }
}
```

## Вариант 2: компоненты-обёртки

- Создаём для каждого пути компонент-обёртку, который будет передавать в исходный компонент нужные данные из `store`
- Мне не нравится данный вариант, так как нужно писать много почти одинаковых компонентов

```
<template>
  <original-component :table="table1" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['table1'])
    }
  }
</script>
```

- [`mapGetters`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/getters.html#%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5n%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-mapgetters)

### Вариант 3: реактивный `$route` с помощью [`vuex-router-sync`](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync)

- Используется библиотека [`vuex-router-sync`](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync)
- Превращаем `data` в `computed` метод, который будет возвращать данные из `store` в зависимости от текущего пути
- Самый простой и чистый вариант

```
export default {
  computed: {
    table() {
      const path = store.state.route.path;
      return store.state...; // выбираем какие данные из store возвращать в зависимости от path
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Могли бы Вы объяснить вот эту запись из первого варианта `this.data = tables[path](this.$store);`, а именно ту часть, что после знака `=`. И еще: как я понял, то код (после `const tables ...`) из первого варианта необходимо писать в моем компоненте?

Comment: @ДмитрийБыстров Да, у нас `tables` это объект, в котором ключ это строка, а значение это функция. Эта функция принимает `store` и возвращает какие-то данные из него. Таким образом, `tables[path]` это значение объекта `tables` по ключу `path`, то есть функция. И мы эту функцию сразу вызываем, передавая в неё `store`. Можно эту запись на две строчки для понятности разбить (`const getter = tables[path]; this.data = getter(this.$store);`), или вообще вместо этой строчки обычные `if`/`else` использовать

Comment: @ДмитрийБыстров Код `const tables = ...` можно как в самом компоненте писать, так и (при желании) в любом другом месте, не забыв его в том месте экспортировать (`export const tables = ...`), а в компоненте импортировать

Answer (score 0):

Или использовать:

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"/>
```

.. это заставит Vue перезагружать компонент при смене роута.